# Fórmula IRR genera error cuando en monto primero es mayor a 1,120,000

Tags: vb6

tengo el siguiente código en visual basic 6, que funciona correctamente, pero al momento de enviarle un monto mayor a -1,200,000 en el primer campo del arreglo, me genera el error 5 en tiempo de ejecución: Llamada a procedimiento o argumento no válido.

[image: 1]

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: No se entiende Bien lo que quieres hacer pero la variable en donde se aloja el dato tiene que ser de tipo Variant para alojarle un Valor Grande. hasta -1.797693134862315E308
si usas tipo Integer solo hasta -32.768.- Saludos!